# Inverse Relationships and UI-Update not working?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I am currently working on a messenger application. Therefore I use realm to store the Data on the device. My app contains a Page to represent all Chatthreads in a Listview. Therefore I binded the ListView to an IRealmCollection. If I change Properties inside the Messagethread I can see that the Litview is updating accordingly. But when I insert a Message into the thread the UI doesn't.

```
public class Messagethread : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    public IList<User.User> Users { get;  }

    [Backlink(nameof(Message.Message.MessageThread))]
    public IQueryable<Message.Message> Messages { get; }

    public User.User Owner { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int CountOfUnreadMessages { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset LastSyncDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastSingleSyncDate { get; set; }
    public int ItemSyncStatus { get; set; }

    public void CallPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(name);
    }
}

public class Message : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    public Messagethread MessageThread { get; set; }
    public User.User Author { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(MessageAttachement.MessageAttachement.Message))]
    public IQueryable<MessageAttachement.MessageAttachement> Attachements { get; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset SendDate { get; set; }
    public bool SystemMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LocalSyncDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ChangeTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsSynced { get; set; }
}
```

I've tryed to call PropertyChanged on the Property "Messages" when I insert a new message. But this also didn't work.

Is there a way to implement a behaviour to automatically update the UI if a Backlink property is changed?

I appreciate any help
Julian

Comment: How are you binding the Backlink'd property (`Messages`) in `Messagethread`?

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover,
I use 
<CustomControls:ThreeLineLabel
                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Text="{Binding Messages, Converter={StaticResource LastMessage}}"
                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
to bind the Backlink'd property.

Comment: I would backlink *from* Message *to* MessageThread, then all the notifications (INotifyPropertyChanged) are updated.. I'll post an example if it would help.

Comment: Hey, @SushiHangover It would be great if you could post me a little example :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick One2Many example, no MVVM/Viper/MVC/MVP and no XAML to keep it as simple as possible.

#### Data Model (simplified version of yours):

`One to Many` navigation  (MessageThread **`->*`** Message)

```
public class MessageThread : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    public IList<Message> Messages { get; }
}

public class Message : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(MessageThread.Guid))]
    public MessageThread Thread { get; }
}
```

#### Simple Master / Detail Forms UI:

[image]

#### `Xamarin.Forms` Application Example:

```
public class BackLinkApp : Application
{
    readonly Realm realm;
    readonly IRealmCollection<MessageThread> allMessageThreads;
    readonly Button addMessageThread;
    readonly Button addMessageToThread;
    IRealmCollection<MessageThread> currentMessageThread;
    string currentMessageThreadPriKey;

    public BackLinkApp()
    {
        realm = Realm.GetInstance("backlinks.realm");
        allMessageThreads = (IRealmCollection<MessageThread>)realm.All<MessageThread>();

        var messageCell = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        messageCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Body");
        messageCell.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "Guid");
        var messageListView = new ListView
        {
            ItemTemplate = messageCell,
        };
        var threadCell = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        threadCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Guid");
        var messageThreadListView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = allMessageThreads,
            ItemTemplate = threadCell
        };

        messageThreadListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            currentMessageThreadPriKey = (messageThreadListView.SelectedItem as MessageThread).Guid;
            currentMessageThread = (IRealmCollection<MessageThread>)realm.All<MessageThread>().Where((messageThread) => messageThread.Guid == currentMessageThreadPriKey);
            messageListView.ItemsSource = currentMessageThread?.FirstOrDefault()?.Messages;
            addMessageToThread.IsEnabled = currentMessageThread?.Count() > 0;
        };

        addMessageThread = new Button { Text = "Add New MessageThread" };
        addMessageThread.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                var messageThread = new MessageThread { Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
                realm.Add(messageThread);
            });
        };

        addMessageToThread = new Button { Text = "Add New Message to Thread", IsEnabled = false };
        addMessageToThread.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                currentMessageThread = (IRealmCollection<MessageThread>)realm.All<MessageThread>().Where((messageThread) => messageThread.Guid == currentMessageThreadPriKey);
                var counter = currentMessageThread.FirstOrDefault().Messages.Count() + 1;
                var message = new Message { Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Body = $"StackoverFlow:{counter}" };
                currentMessageThread?.FirstOrDefault()?.Messages.Add(message);
            });
        };

        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    addMessageThread, messageThreadListView, addMessageToThread, messageListView
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

By setting the binding source of `messageListView.ItemsSource` to the `Messages` property of the *currently* selected `MessageThread` object, your UI will "auto" update when a new message is added to that thread:

```
messageListView.ItemsSource = currentMessageThread?.FirstOrDefault()?.Messages;
```

[image]

Comment: I get the Idea behind your example. I'll try it out.
However I get the "Message.MessageThread has [Backlink] applied, but is not IQueryable" compile error. 
I guess it will still work without the backlink.
I'll let you know!

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for your help and spending your time on my problem!