# ListView not updating on CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, realm

I am starting to play with Realm, and I am trying to bind a collection from the Realm database to a `ListView`. The binding works fine, but my `ListView` does not update when adding new items. My understanding is that `IRealmCollection<>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` events.

Here is a simple application to reproduce the issue:

`View`:

```
<Page x:Class="App3.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:App3"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Add" />
            <ListView x:Name="ListView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

`CodeBehind`:

```
namespace App3
{
    public class Thing : RealmObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Realm _realm;
        private IRealmCollection<Thing> things;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
            things = (IRealmCollection<Thing>)_realm.All<Thing>();

            ListView.ItemsSource = things;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _realm.Write(() =>
            {
                var thing = new Thing();
                _realm.Add(thing);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I normally use MVVM (Template10), but this is a simple application to demonstrate the issue. Clicking the `Add` button adds an item to the database, but the `ListView` only updates when the application is first loaded. I have read similar questions, but I have not been able to find an answer that works yet. [Inverse Relationships and UI-Update not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647176/inverse-relationships-and-ui-update-not-working) is the closest I have found yet, but still does not fix the issue.

**EDIT**

I can force it to rebind like so:

```
ListView.ItemsSource = null;
ListView.ItemsSource = things;
```

But that is not optimal. I am trying to take advantage of Realm's "live objects" where the collection should always know when items are changed or added.

**EDIT 2**

Setting `BindingMode=OneWay` in code-behind also does not change the behavior:

```
_realm = Realm.GetInstance();
things = (IRealmCollection<Thing>)_realm.All<Thing>();

var binding = new Binding
{
    Source = things,
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
};

ListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

**SOLUTION**

It turned out to be a known issue in `IRealmCollection`: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1461#issuecomment-312489046 which is fixed in Realm 1.6.0. I have updated to the pre-release NuGet package and can confirm that the `ListView` now updates as expected.

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379770/6611487) which was posted by me. Might work in your case

Comment: The item is added to database but the 'things' collection which you use as ItemSource for ListView does not know about the new item that was added. so you need to requery from the database new items and load them in the 'things' collection.

Comment: @Nobody no luck. The `UpdateLayout` method didn't make a difference, and it looks like `InvalidateVisual` doesn't exist for UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Mode=OneWay` in `Binding`

#### Method 1: In Xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind things, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

#### Method 2: In Code Behind

```
Binding myBind = new Binding();
myBind.Source = things;
myBind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
myListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, myBind);
```

---

It is a bug in IRealmCollection. You can use [Prerelease Nuget](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45yfBWnWXwAajhyLVkxeWNmOFE/view?usp=sharing) to solve it.

For more info:
[IRealmCollection does not update UWP ListView](https://forums.realm.io/t/irealmcollection-does-not-update-uwp-listview/386)
[GitHub Issue: IRealmCollection does not update UWP ListView](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1461)

Comment: The `TextBlock` binding doesn't affect the `ListView.ItemsSource` binding. Changing the binding of the `ListView` to `OneWay` also doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Use `Mode=OneWay` for your `ListView`. I have updated my answer

Comment: So far, the only thing that I can get to update the `ListView` is to set the `ItemsSource` to `null` and re-bind. See updated question.

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything. It seems like the CollectionChanged is not firing or something like that to notify the `ListView` to refresh the `ItemsSource`....

Comment: @dubstylee Attach some sample code for your `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150432/discussion-between-dub-stylee-and-vijay-nirmal).

Comment: Your answer would work, if not for a bug in Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1461 thanks!